# How can I run code from my layout file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I used the following tutorial to help me build an RSS Reader in my ASP.NET MVC3 Razor application:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2011/08/17/creating-basic-rss-reader-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

However, unlike the tutorial example, I want the RSS feed to be displayed on every page, and have therefore added it to my layout file, `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`

I currently only have 2 views on my site, and to get the RSS Reader to work on both views I've got the following code in my `HomeController`:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Index/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(CT.Models.RssReader.GetRssFeed());
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View(CT.Models.RssReader.GetRssFeed());
        }

    }
```

From my WebForms experience, I would simply add the RSS Reader code in my master page code behind, and it would automatically work on every page.

Is there a Controller for layout pages which allows me to do the same?

How can I get this to work on every call of the layout page, without having to return anything?

---

**EDIT:** Following @Sebastian's advice, I've now added this code to a Partial View, removed `CT.Models.RssReader.GetRssFeed()` from `return View()` and included this in my layout file:

```
 @Html.Partial("_MyPartialView")
```

The code in this partial view is:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <li>
         <a href="@item.Link" target="_blank">@item.Title</a>
      </li>
    }
</ul>
```

However, I'm not getting a runtime error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It's erroring on the line `@foreach (var item in Model)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create a partial view and add functionality there.
Then in your layout, render this partial.

**EDIT**

Is your partial view really a partial view? The reason I said that is because you have "_" in front of the name which suggests that it might be a layout (might just be a naming convention).

To fix object reference error, you have to add the @Model declaration on top of your partial view.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**
In order to use different model in partial view, you need to explicitly declare which model you are going to use on render partialmethod.

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("../YourFeed", Model.YourFeedModel);}
```

Let me know if that resolved your issue.

Comment: Cheers for your help, but I'm now getting another error. Please see the edit in my question

Comment: Ah thats just my poor convention naming then, I saw a tutorial which used underscores for partial views and copied that. I have `@model IEnumerable<CT.Models.Rss>` on the top line of my partial view, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: yeah, sorry - my fault. your naming convention is right. I'm trying to reproduce it now and shall get back to you soon

Answer (score 1):

The new error you are having is due to you not passing a Model to the partial view. You can do this with the second argument of the `Html.Partial` function...

```
Html.Partial("ViewName", MyModel);
```

As I think you are trying to do this in a Layout page you could also consider using a static reference to get your RSS feed. So forget about needing to pass in a Model and in your partial have:

```
@foreach (var item in RssRepository.GetFeed())
{
  <li>
     <a href="@item.Link" target="_blank">@item.Title</a>
  </li>
}
```

this like to a class something like...

```
public static RssRepository
{
   public static MyModel GetFeed()
   {
      return new MyModel();//<- return what you would normally pass as a Model for RSS feeds
   }
}
```

Hope that all makes sense